# Laravel: Database is not storing my image but showing me only array

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-controller

I am new to Laravel. I have been trying to save an image to the database. Here is my controller method that I am trying for storing the image

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        //validation for form

        $validate= $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:2|max:140',
            'position' => 'required|min:2|max:140',
            'salary' => 'required|min:2|max:140',
            'joining_date' => ''
        ]);


        //saving form

        if($validate){            
            $employee=new Employee;
            $employee->name =$request->input('name');
            $employee->company_name =$request->input('company_name');
            $employee->position =$request->input('position');
            $employee->salary =$request->input('salary');
            $employee->joining_date =$request->input('joining_date');
            $employee->user_id= auth()->user()->id;
            //image saveing method
            if($request->hasFile('image')){
                $image= $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                Employee::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/employee/images/' . $filename ) );

                $employee->image= $filename;

              }else{
                  return $request;
                  $employee->image= '';
              };

             $employee->save();

        //redirecting to Employee list
            return redirect('/employee/details')->with('success','Employee Added');
        }
```

I could save the form while there was no image and redirect it to the details page. but now when I try with the image, instead of saving it and redirecting to the details route, it returns me to the array of row of database like this:

```
{
  "_token": "FPHm9AKuEbRlqQnSgHhjPnCEKidi2xr0usgp7RoW",
  "name": "askfjlk",
  "company_name": "laksjsflkj",
  "position": "lkasjfkl",
  "salary": "35454",
  "joining_date": "4654-05-06",
  "image": "testing.png"
}
```

What did I do wrong here? please help me out this newb.

Comment: because you are returning the Request object from your Controller method .. this will cause it to return the inputs serialized as JSON ... apparently `$request->hasFile('image')` is false ... how are you sending this data?

Comment: if ` $request->hasFile('image')` is false how am I supposed to check if there is any image or not? I am using form to send the data and `return redirect('/employee/details')->with('success','Employee Added');` using this to redirect. i dont understand how am I returning JSON array. @Kamran

Answer (score 0):

You are returning **$request** object and Laravel does automatic JSON response.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')){
    // image storing logic which obviously is never started because expression above is false
} else {
    return $request; // There is your problem
    $employee->image= '';
};
```

You need to check why you are getting **false** on **$request->hasFile('image')**.

Also, one tip because you are new to Laravel:

```
// When you are accessing to $request object you can use dynamic propertes:
$employee->company_name = $request->input('company_name');
// is the same as
$employee->company_name = $request->company_name;
```

You can check it there: [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#retrieving-input) in the section: Retrieving Input Via Dynamic Properties